# Regex for AA/AA/AAAA

Tags: regex

I am really rubbish at regex, could any one help me write to validate the the following format:

AA/AA/AAAA

A = any letter lowercase or uppercase
/ = must have a slash

must have the following length:
2/2/4

Comment: Any letter? Including Unicode? And what about  diacritics? Then, what is the regex flavor? Perhaps, you already tried something, please share.

Comment: google is your friend :) and see here:  https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: which programming language? are the letters repeated?

Comment: Well, Cyrillic letters are also letters. You should specify your requirements in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([a-zA-Z]|[^0-9]){2}\/([a-zA-Z]|[^0-9]){2}\/([a-zA-Z]|[^0-9]){4}

[a-zA-Z] = any letter
[^0-9] = not a digit
```